# Bitmap pixel values differ after setPixel() and getPixel() on same pixel

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap, steganography

I'm developing a steganography app for a class project which allows a user to encode a secret message image with in another image. I use `Bitmap.getPixel(x,y)` to retrieve pixel information after modifying the pixel integer value to contain the message value. I then used `Bitmap.setPixel(x,y)` to place the modified pixel in the bitmap. After decoding the image and retrieving the hidden message I've noticed some pixels were discolored. I've found that certain pixels do not contain the correct value after being modified. if I use

```
int before = encoded_value;
bitmap.setPixel(x,y, before);
int after = bitamp.getPixel(x,y);
```

for most of the pixels before==after however on some before!=after. If I continuously modify before by adding or subtracting one( this only changes the color slightly in the message image ) and then set the pixel again the values of before and after still differ. Having a few pixels off in the decoded image wouldn't be that big of a deal. However, when one of the problem pixels shows up where I encoded the message image information( the images dimensions ) the decoded dimensions will usually contain a non digit value such as "2q3x300". Which will through an exception when the application tries to turn this string into integer values. I've also tried to get and set pixels using a integer buffer however the same pixels cause problem. Also through some debugging I've found that certain pixels cause problems and certain values cause problems if I encode the image with with a doubled dimension string "213213x300300" the string is decoded from the image as "2q32q3x300300". I'm not sure if this is a problem that start when decoding the bitmap from an image file or its a bug in the getPixel() and setPixel() methods. It seems that certain pixels cause a bit to be off. In the above example 1( which contains an ascii value of 49 or 00110001) is decoded as q( which contains an ascii value of 113 or 01110001) only a single bit value differs from the set and get however it can cause bit problems. The Bitmap is in ARGB_8888 and thus should be able to contain any value that can also be contained in an integer value. For the stereography to work I'm modifying the least 2 bits of the alpha, red, green and blue values to store 1 byte. I reduce the message image to RGB_332 so that It can be contained in the least bits. One more example is trying to set a pixel to -53029643.

```
I put           -53029643 = 1111 1100 1101 0110 1101 0100 1111 0101
and get returns -53029387 = 1111 1100 1101 0110 1101 0101 1111 0101
                ----------------------------------------------------XOR
                          = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 = 256
```

Although these two only differ in the least bit of the green value. The decoding of this integer value by taking the least 2 bits from each bit yields 00100101 instead of 00100001 the bytes are in the form RRRGGGBB thus green value is changing from 000 to 001 and the resulting bit map will contain a pixel with a green value of 001000 instead of 000000 since the decoded bit map is in RGB_565 and thuse the decimal value from green is 8 instead of 0. Here the 3 png images the first is the carrier image( the image that has the message image encoded into it) the second is the message image( the image that is encoded in the carrier image) and the third is the message image after it has been decoded from the carrier image.

carrier image

[image: carrier image]

message image

[image: message image]

decoded message image. This image is in 8 bit color the pixels that are more red or green are the ones affected by this error.

[image: decoded message]

Comment: After the image is encoded it is saved in .png format since this is the only lossless type a bitmap can be compressed to.

Comment: I've reformatted the image dimensions to be contained by 3 bytes the first 12bits for the width and the last 12bits for height. This doesn't solve the error however the chance of the error occurring in the first 3 pixels are less then they were with the previous format that was would take at least the first 5 pixels if the x and y components were both < 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This defect](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7921&q=bitmap%20pixel&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) in the android api appears to relate to the same issue i'm having. Since there was no way to solve this issue while creating the bitmap from a pixel array or when decoding into the message image I've had to resort to using image filtering after the image has been decoded. I'm using a median filter that has been modified to target problem pixels here is an example of an image with and without the median filter.

unfiltered

[image: unfiltered]

filtered

[image: filtered]

Answer (score 1):

This looks very much like an issue I had where (only on some devices) bitmaps loaded from the drawables folder would be changed slightly.  I solved it by putting the bitmaps in the "raw" folder (e.g. res\raw).  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your bitmap is probably set up as 565, i.e. 5 bits for red, 6 for green, 5 for blue. As such, you can only have 32 distinct values for red/blue and 64 for green.

If you need more precision, you need to create an 8888 bitmap.

Example:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(128, 128, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Comment: Sorry, was just thinking I should have added that to the question the Bitmap is in ARGB_8888 and thus should be able to contain any value that can also be contained in an integer value. For the steganography to work I'm modifying the least 2 bits of the alpha, red, green and blue values to store 1 byte. I reduce the message image to RGB_332 so that It can be contained in the least bits

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I was able to solve the issue by alternating adding and subtracting 1 from each incorrect byte in the ARGB integer until the least significant bit of each of those bytes was correct.  I believe this is the optimally closest the pixel can get while having the least significant bit of each byte correct.

Additionally, I have reported this bug to google.