# Why is there a slight bitmap mismatch between saved png, and, opened png

Tags: android, bitmap, png

I am attempting to hide a small file within a bitmap.  I am setting the least significant bit of ARGB to each bit in the file (the first few pixels of the bitmap I have reserved for file size).

For this debugging purpose, I am comparing the encoded int[] to the decoded int[].  Every few hundred bytes, there is an incorrect bit.

I am saving the picture through the Bitmap.compress method like so...

```
OutputStream out = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(fileUri);

picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,out);
```

Then, when extracting the file from the image...

```
pic = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), fileUri);

pic.getPixels(intArr, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
```

I took the liberty of examining one of these pngs, and I am indeed using argb8 as the config, and, using tweakPNG, have discovered that the only chuncks in the generated file are 
IHDR: 8 bits/sample, truecolor+alpha, noninterlaced
sBIT: RGBA8
IDAT
IEND

The PNG photo looks fine, and has no issues.

Edit: progress!

I tracked the bug down to this basic issue.
Bitmap.setPixels is not functioning identically to Bitmap.getpixels.

The following code shows a slight difference between converted and converted2. Roughly 1 or two bits per hundred ints.  This seems shocking to me.  Is that an android bug?

```
    picture3 = Bitmap.createBitmap(picture1.getWidth(), picture1.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    picture3.setPixels(converted,0,picture1.getWidth(),0,0,picture1.getWidth(), picture1.getHeight());
    int[] converted2 = new int[converted.length];
    picture3.getPixels(converted2,0,picture1.getWidth(),0,0,picture1.getWidth(), picture1.getHeight());
```

Comment: What do you consider to be the lsb of an argb value?

Comment: `attempting to hide a small file within a bitmap`. It looks more like hiding in a png file.

Comment: greenapps: lsb is A: XXXXXXX_ R: XXXXXXX_ G: XXXXXXX_ B: XXXXXXX_ Where X is the bits of the pixels, and _ is the bit of the file.  So, each byte of the file gets stored on 8 bytes of the pixels, or, the 2 ints of the pixel files represented as 32 bit argb colors.  And, yes, I am storing in the bitmap and compressing to png, as, png is supposed to be lossless.

Comment: So with setting the `lsb of an argb value` you ment setting the lsb of each of the four bytes of an argb integer.

Comment: ah, yes, correct, sorry for poor wording

Comment: `getting very peculiar results. `. Its time you elaborate.

Comment: when I save the png via... picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,out); sometimes only half of the png is showing.  sometimes all of it is showing.  sometimes, when decoding, the bits of the file are off slightly, and sometimes they are perfect.

Comment: Start by reading [how to provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and make sure you edit all of the necessary info in the body of the question.

Comment: In addition of above comment, you should be sure that the file is ARGB8 and no color correction chunks (iCCP, gAMA, sRGB). YOu can use http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/ to check.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same issue as in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175328/bitmap-pixel-values-differ-after-setpixel-and-getpixel-on-same-pixel).

I have a simple solution, just increment and decriment the off A, R, G, or B value until the lsb if each is correct.  Obviously this will result in a more distorted bitmap, but it seems to be the only solution I can think of.